# How to run methods against the entire bytes of a large file

Tags: java, arrays, inputstream, out-of-memory

My program needs to do calculations against the entire bytes of a file and it breaks whenever the file gets above a certain size.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

I know I can allocate the amount of memory to my program using command line switches, but I'm wondering if there is a more effective way of handling this in my program?

I'm basically trying to figure out a way to read the file in chunks and pass those chunks to another method and essentially rebuild the file in that method.

This is the problem method.  I need these bytes to be used in another method.

This method converts the stream to a byte array:

```
private byte[] inputStreamToByteArray(InputStream inputStream) {
   BufferedInputStream bis = null;
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;

   try {
      bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
      baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bis);

      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

      int nRead;
      while((nRead = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
         baos.write(buffer, 0, nRead);
      }
   } catch(IOException ioe) {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
   }

   return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

This method checks the file type:

```
private final boolean isMyFileType(byte[] bytes) { 
   // do stuff

   return theBoolean;
}
```

The reason it is breaking makes sense to me - the byte array ends up being gigantic if I have a gigantic file AND I'm passing around a gigantic byte array.

My goal, I want to read the bytes from a file, determine what type of file it is using another method I wrote, run compression/decompression method against those bytes after determining the file type.

I have most of my goal completed, I just don't know how to handle file streams and large byte arrays effectively.

Comment: You need to change the method to only process a single chunk at a time.

Comment: @SLaks how do I do that?

Comment: Basically, if you need the whole byte array in memory (not sure if you really need it, it depends on what you do with this byte array), I don't think there is anything else to do than increase the memory available to the JVM.

Comment: @mael I'm compressing and decompressing files... I THINK I need the entire file in memory, but I'm a noob and don't know better.

Comment: I can't help you about compressing and decompressing, I am ignorant on that topic. But I am not sure that the compression tools usually load the entire files in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using a BufferedInputStream. Use the "mark" method to place a mark in the steam. Make sure the "readlimit" argument to "mark" is large enough for you to detect the file type. Read the first X bytes from the stream (but not more than readlimit) and try to figure out the content. Then call reset() to set the stream back to the beginning and continue withw whatever you want to do with the stream.